# Can't find "matplotlib.markers" even with Matplotlib installed

Tags: python, matplotlib, module, anaconda, python-module

I realize this seems like a generic question, but all answers pointed to having two simultanious `python` installations - I already uninstalled the other one.

Currently I run my code from *PyCharm 2017.1.5* (windows 10) with Python interpreter set as `Python 3.6.1 (C:\Anaconda3\python.exe)`, i.e. I installed *Anaconda3*, which includes the `matplotlib`, and run from *PyCharm* using the *Ananconda3*-interpreter.

I've checked in *Anaconda Navigator* that `matplotlib 2.0.2` is installed in the environment.

A minimal (non-working) example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
```

Returns the following error:

```
C:\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/John/Documents/CPU/master/untitled/main11.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/John/Documents/CPU/master/untitled/main11.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 29, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 34, in <module>
    import matplotlib.collections as collections
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 37, in <module>
    import matplotlib.lines as mlines
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 28, in <module>
    from matplotlib.markers import MarkerStyle
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.markers'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This ran fine 2 weeks ago, but not now. To my knowledge, I didn't change or update anything. The module loads correctly, but it seems to be a change in the module content? If so: How did that happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: It seems, something went wrong during installation or uninstallation of matplotlib. Did you try to remove matplotlib and reinstall it?

Comment: I then get `(C:\Anaconda3) C:\Users\Rasmus>conda install matplotlib [...]
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::matplotlib-2.0.2-np112py36_0'.
OSError(22, 'Invalid argument')
Attempting to roll back.


OSError(22, 'Invalid argument')`

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5432 suggests this might be an error between 32 and 64 bit python or characterset errors. I don't use non-ascii in the `PATH`. I'll try to reinstall from scratch...

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest! I found the error (HDD corruption) and posted my solution below based on your inspiration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@ImportanceOfBeingErnest lead me in the right direction. I post my solution here  s.t. others may find the answer. The problem was a corrupted disk sector - an unlikely event of chance.

The problem was indeed in the `matplotlib`-package itself. Retrospectively, pointers to the issue were that errors in pre-distributed packages should not exist. If they do, external circumstances must have corrupted and the problem is not with the Python-installation itself.

I uninstalled `matplotlib` through *Anaconda Prompt* with `conda remove matplotlib` and re-installed with `conda install matplotlib`. This gave me this error:

```
(C:\Anaconda3) C:\Users\John>conda install matplotlib
[...]
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::matplotlib-2.0.2-np112py36_0'.
OSError(22, 'Invalid argument') Attempting to roll back. 

OSError(22, 'Invalid argument')
```

Before @Ernest's comment, I thought it maybe had to do with [non-ASCII in `PATH` or similar](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5432).

Instead I tried to reinstall *Anaconda3* completely, restarted and found that part of the Anaconda3-folder weren't removed (the one containing the `matplotlib`).

Deleting it manually gave a Windows error `0x80070570`. Following [this post on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/63641/error-0x80070570-how-to-delete-corrupted-and-unreadable-file) (the comment to OP) I ran a check and afterwards a repair from *Windows Explorer GUI*: Right-click on the drive in *This PC* --> *Properties* --> Tab *Tools* --> *Check* (*repair* appears if any errors are found).

After some restarts, reinstalling *Anaconda3* from scratch and restarting again, I was able to run my project again!

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I could fix it by setting `PYTHONPATH` to the path to `site-packages` folder where the needed packages are located, excluding `site-pacages`.

I use a `pyenv` virtual environment, whose path is `/home/apk/.pyenv/versions/python-3-7-4`. When the environment is activated, `pip` installs packages to `/home/apk/.pyenv/versions/python-3-7-4/lib/python3.7/site-packages`. Therefore, in terminal, I set:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=/home/apk/.pyenv/versions/python-3-7-4/lib/python3.7/
```

The same should be true for Windows installations of `python`. 
If virtual environmets are used, then one could edit `activate` script to set `PYTHONPATH`.

After I did it, I checked in a `python` shell.

```
$ python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Feb  5 2020, 17:11:33) 
[GCC 5.5.0 20171010] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/apk/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python37.zip', '/home/apk/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7', '/home/apk/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/apk/.pyenv/versions/python-3-7-4/lib/python3.7']
>>> sys.executable
'/home/apk/.pyenv/versions/python-3-7-4/bin/python'
```

Good luck!

#### References

- https://github.community/t5/Programming-Help-and-Discussion/Python-ModuleNotFoundError-although-module-is-installed-aiohttp/td-p/28525

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer this question directly, however, I have seen a large amount of issues in corporate Windows environments with PyCharm and Anaconda these are some of the issues you may be having

1. Check you `PATH` is correctly pointing to all Anaconda locations

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path
   ```
2. Check that your files have not been migrated to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming` by your  IT team
3. Purge your system for any `python` distributions. There may be software distributions that you use internally that package their own `python` distribution. This can often be included in the `PATH`. Another example could be installing Anaconda to your `C:\` but also having it already installed in `Users\Local\AppData` or `'C:\Program Files'` months before and forgotten!

A good way of directly debugging your problem would be to navigate to the following directory in `ipython`

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib
```

and they try `import matplotlib.markers`

If this fails then you could then try

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.__file__
```

you should check that this result gives

```
'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\__init__.pyc'
```

as most likely there will be another `matplotlib` version installed that is taking precedence. This will then fall under one of the issues above to correct.

Comment: I think a pointer to why your answer (in this specific case) is not usable, is that the error is in a small part of `matplotlib` only. If not for the comment by @Ernest, the last part of your answer may have aided me a bit (would probably have resulted in the import failing).

Comment: yeah I try make my answers generic to other problems :)

Answer (score -1):

Got the same type of error while using pip. created new VENV and execute the app agaist that resolved my issue

Answer (score -2):

PyCharm requires installing packages available in the interpreter.

You can find matplotlib and other packages available for an install using the following steps:

1. Open the File--Settings--Project--Project Interpreter menu.
2. You should see all packages you currently have installed, and matplotlib should be missing from this list.
3. Click the + (add) button to the right and install the matplotlib package.
4. Once complete, close the top dialog box, and you should see matplotlib in the list of installed packages.

Comment: As the problem states, the issue was not an uninstalled package, but a corruption of a subpackage!